# sending data from html form to mysql database using node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, forms

I'm making an app and I'd like to have a register page. Here is the html form :

```
<form method="post" action="/register">
  <p>Nom <input type='text' id="nom"></p>
  <p>Prénom <input type='text' id="prenom"></p>
  <p>Mot de passe <input type='text' id="mdp"></p>
  <p>Email <input type='text' id="email"></p>
  <input type="submit" value="Valider" id="envoyer">
 </form>
```

my server.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var async = require('async');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var mysql = require('mysql');
var hostname = 'localhost';
var port = 3000;
var app = express();

////////////////
//   MYSQL    //
////////////////

const connection = require('./config/database');

connection.connect(function (err){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Le serveur s'est bien connecté sur la base de donnée MYSQL")
});

////////////////
//   ROUTING  //
////////////////

var home = require('./app/routes/home');
var login = require('./app/routes/users/login');
var register = require('./app/routes/users/register');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', home);
app.get('/login/', login);
app.post('/register/', register);

////////////////
//   SERVER   //
////////////////

app.listen(port, hostname, function(){
    console.log("Mon serveur fonctionne sur http://"+ hostname +":"+port);
});
```

my register.js :

```
module.exports = (function() {
    'use strict';

    const connection = require('../../../config/database');
    var router = require('express').Router();
    var User = require('../../models/User');

    router.get('/register', function(req, res) {
      console.log(req.body.firstname)
        User.addUser(req.query.firstname, req.query.lastname, req.query.email, req.query.password,function(err,rows){
          if(err)
          {
              return res.json({
                  'code':'500',
                  'success':'false',
                  'msg': err
              });
            }

            else{
                    return res.json({
                        'code':'200',
                        'success':'true',
                        'msg':'Bonjour '+rows[0].firstname+', vous avez bien été créé'
                    });
            }

        });
    });
    return router;
})();
```

my user.js :

```
  addUser:function(firstname,lastname,email,password,callback){

        return db.query
            (
              "INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (?,?,?,?)"
+                [firstname,lastname,email,password],
                callback
            );
    },
```

but when I enter some values in my form I get this error :

```
The requested URL /register was not found on this server.
```

I don't know where I'm missing something has anyone any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should remove the trailing slashes when you define your routes:

```
app.post('/register', register);
```

In your server.js file, you have already established your /register route to be a POST route and have set the handler as your register.js module. The request data is sent directly to that function so there is no need to setup a new route inside of it. Here is an example of what your register.js should look like:

```
'use strict';

const connection = require('../../../config/database');
const User = require('../../models/User');

module.exports = function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.firstname);
    User.addUser(req.body.firstname, req.body.lastname, req.body.email, req.body.password,function(err,rows){
      if(err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
                'code':'500',
                'success':'false',
                'msg': err});
      } else {
        return res.status(200).json({
                'code':'200',
                 'success':'true',
                 'msg':'Bonjour '+rows[0].firstname+', vous avez bien été créé'});
      }
    });

  });
};
```

Also, when creating your form inputs, you must include a name on each one so the server knows which property is which.

So on your 'first name' input, set the name attribute of the input element as something like 'firstname'. Then when the server receives a request, you can access 'firstname' in req.body.

Your HTML input should look like this:

```
<input type='text' name="firstname" id="someid">
```

Then in your register.js, you can access that variable like this:

```
req.body.firstname
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer !  I did make the changes but still get the same error :/

Comment: @SamCaneau did you take off the trailing slash on '/register/'?

Comment: Yes @hyrumcoop I remove the trailing slash and set name attribute but the same error still (The requested URL /register was not found on this server.). 
When I tried on Postman it gives me this : 
{
    "code": "500",
    "success": "false",
    "msg": {
        "code": "ER_PARSE_ERROR",
        "errno": 1064,
        "sqlState": "42000",
        "index": 0
    }
}

Comment: In your 'INSERT INTO' SQL statement, try replacing the question marks with the actual column names. For example: "INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (firstname,lastname,email,password)". The question marks must be replaced by the actual column names in the database.

Comment: Still doesn't not found the route /register .. I don't understand where the error comes from

Comment: Try the new code for register.js. There was a syntax error I missed because I'm on mobile right now.

Comment: I am not node expert but the error 1046 is access denied issue check the mysql [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_dbaccess_denied_error)

Comment: It says it's a mysql syntaxe error but I don't see what is the error in my query

Comment: Add a semi-colon to the end of the SQL statement ("INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (?,?,?,?);"). Also, try logging the inputs you are sending to the database using console.log.

Comment: I did all that and I still get the syntax error, I've been trying all the way possible to write that query and I still getting the same error I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

```
addUser:function(firstname,lastname,email,password,callback){

        return db.query
            (
              "INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (?,?,?,?)"
+                [firstname,lastname,email,password],
                callback
            );
    },
```

The error comes from syntaxe error there is a "+" after "INSERT INTO" that I should remove  :

```
addUser:function(firstname,lastname,email,password,callback){

        return db.query
            (
              "INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (?,?,?,?)"
             [firstname,lastname,email,password],
                callback
            );
    },
```

Thx all for your answers !